# Text Input Amount Formatting

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react-native and I have used a text input for entering numbers but I'm not able to format the value i.e, when I enter 5555 or 5555.5 I want it to be  5,555.00 or 5,555.50. Can anyone help me with this?
     Thanks.

```
export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      amount: 0.0
    };
  }

  numberformat(amount) {
    this.setState({
      num: Number(amount).toFixed(2)
    });
  }


  render() {
    console.log('numberFormat', this.state.amount);
    return (
      <TextInput
        placeholder={this.state.amount.fixed(2)}
        onChangeText={(amount) => this.numberformat(amount)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this.setState({num: Number(num).toFixed(2)}) why you are assign value to num ?instead of num, it should be amount!

Comment: Yes, it should be amount. In console.log I get desired output but it's not reflecting in the placeholder. So any idea ??

Comment: value={this.state.amount.fixed(2)}

Comment: Using value={this.state.amount.fixed(2)} will not let me to edit.

Comment: try to use onBlur event to validate number you entered instead of onChangeText

Answer (score 1):

Use **Intl​.Number​Format**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { amount: 0.0 };
  }
  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    let amount = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(target.value);
    this.setState({
      amount
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.amount}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Source - [Mozilla Number Format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Comment: On editing the number it does not format within the text input

Comment: You can do something like this:

text = text && text.match(/\d/g);
text = text && text.join('');
text = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(text)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `toFixed(2)`

example if your value is

```
num=5555.5
```

OR

```
num = 5;
n = num.toFixed(2);
console.log(n)
```

and for comma

You can use this function

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

reference

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html#addcommas

Comment: But this will not apply the said formatting of say comma like the question asks. 5555 --> 5,555.00

Comment: This doesn't work when I try to edit. It still shows without decimal values.

Comment: @Raj.S can you please show your code where you put this?

Comment: @Paras Korat I have updated my code in the question

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be the `Intl.NumberFormat` object which is a constructor for objects that enable language sensitive number formatting.

```
 export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  state = {
     amount: new Intl.NumberFormat({style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'}).format(number))
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        placeholder = {this.state.amount.fixed(2)}
        onChangeText={(amount) => this.setState({amount})}
        value={this.state.amount}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

More resources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Answer (score 0):

This library [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) can be helpful

1. Prefix, suffix and thousand separator.
2. Custom format pattern.
3. Masking.
4. Custom formatting handler.
5. Format number in an input or
       format as a simple text

Sample usage

```
<NumberFormat value={2456981} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
```

Output : $2,456,981

[Demo](http://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/jobike-1524611432106/testlab/histories/bh.5c33b14e692e2079)

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      amount: 0.0,
      num: ''
    };
  }

  numberformat(num) {
    this.setState({
      num: Number(num).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    });
  }


  render() {
    console.log('numberFormat', this.state.amount);
    return (
      <TextInput
        placeholder={this.state.amount}
        value={this.state.num}
        onChangeText={(amount) => this.numberformat(amount)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```